# how to list all the pdf file from mobile storage?? this code is work for all Png, jpg. mp3

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-studio-3.0

I want to list all the pdf files and store them into Array List of type File but its not work.. code is working fine for jpg,png,mp3,mp4 but did not read any pdf.

here is my method to read pdf file:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private List<File> getPDFFilesListInDirectory(File directory) {
    List<File> pdfFilesList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (directory.isDirectory()) {
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();

        if (files != null) {

            for (File file : files) {
                Log.d("name", "getPDFFilesListInDirectory: "+file.getName());
                if (file.isFile() && file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    pdfFilesList.add(file);
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    pdfFilesList.addAll(getPDFFilesListInDirectory(file));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return pdfFilesList;
}
```

this method reads all the folders but did not read any pdf file. also I give read and write external storage permission

Comment: It is unclear at which directory you start to list. Please show how you call that function.

Comment: Also tell Android version of used device.

Comment: Also tell if those pdf files are created by your app.

Comment: You do not have access to arbitrary files on external storage. Please use the Storage Access Framework to allow the user to browse for PDF files using a system-supplied UI.